# calling window.location.reload only once in $ionicPlatform.ready [Ionic]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am calling an OAuth Process in the device ready function using InAppBrowser in app.js where i am getting a token and upon checking of that token i am redirecting to a particular view.

```
.run(function($ionicPlatform,$rootScope,$http,jwtHelper,$cordovaInAppBrowser,$state,jwtHelper) {
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
  if(isValidUser)
   {
       $state.go('app.playlists');
       window.location.reload(true);
   }
}
```

Now the window.location.reload is redirecting to the view but it is falling inside an infinite loop. If i only write $state.go, it is not redirecting to the view.

Also, when i put

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/playlists');
```

The above view gets fired for 2 secs and then my oauth login screen gets fired(Inside inappbrowser). So, i can't use that.

How to fix it.

Comment: Do you really want to **reload**, or just to redirect?

Comment: @Mistalis i just want to redirect, no reloading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use [`$location.path`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location) instead of `$state.go`:

```
$location.path('/app/playlists');
```

---

*Note: Don't forget to inject $location.*